# declare and give value to variables stored in a table

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a table `vars` containing variables only. There are three columns:
`id` - id
`name` - variable name
`val` - variable value

I need to declare that variables and give them corresponding values, something like:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM vars order by id asc");
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    '$' . $row['name'] = "'" . $row['val'] . "'";
}

echo $somevariable...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM vars order by id asc");
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    ${$row['name']} = $row['val'];
}
```

Try this
However you need to make sure that $row['name'] is compliant with PHP variable naming requirements

Comment: It works. Any link about `compliant with PHP...`, pls

Comment: Rules for PHP variables:


A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character

A variable name cannot start with a number

A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
${$row['name']} = $row['val'];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do something  like this

```
$$row['name'] = $row['val'];
```

Comment: @bonaca: are you putting my  code in your loop? According to PHP  document, my solution should be correct. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: yes, I tried, of course. All variables are undefined, at echoing them.